# Lasagna plot for continuous data

Tags: r, longitudinal

This code works fine for categorical data

```
library(longCatEDA)
library(colorspace)
set.seed(642531)
y <- matrix(sample(1:24, 500, replace=TRUE), 100, 5)
set.seed(963854)
times <- matrix(runif(600, 1, 3), 100, 6)

# times must be cumulative
times <- t(apply(times, 1, cumsum))
lc <- longCat(y, times=times)

par(mfrow=c(1,1), bg='white', mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 10.1), xpd=TRUE)


cols <- longCatPlot(lc,  colScheme='heat', legendBuffer=0, groupBuffer=0,main='Individually test Varying Times of Observation')
legend(15.5, 100, legend=lc$Labels, lty=1, col=cols, lwd=2)
```

[image]

But as shown in the figure, if I have a lot of categories (more than 10) the legend should be a continuous scale instead of 24 categories.
In the `longCatEDA` library they recommend to use `longContPlot` in this cases, I'm trying something like this:

```
longContPlot(lc, times, jog=TRUE, main='Individually varying times', ylab='', xlab='Days')
```

But it is not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to do it in `longCatEDA` but using the `color.legend` function in plotrix this is quite easy:

```
library(colorspace)
library(plotrix)
set.seed(642531)
y <- matrix(sample(1:24, 500, replace=TRUE), 100, 5)
set.seed(963854)
times <- matrix(runif(600, 1, 3), 100, 6)

# times must be cumulative
times <- t(apply(times, 1, cumsum))
lc <- longCat(y, times=times)

par(mfrow=c(1,1), bg='white', mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 10.1), xpd=TRUE)


cols <- longCatPlot(lc,  colScheme='heat', legendBuffer=0, groupBuffer=0,main='Individually test Varying Times of Observation')
plotrix::color.legend(xl=par('usr')[1]+1.05*(par('usr')[2]-par('usr')[1]),
                      xr=par('usr')[1]+1.15*(par('usr')[2]-par('usr')[1]),
                      yb=par('usr')[3]+0.20*(par('usr')[4]-par('usr')[3]),
                      yt=par('usr')[3]+0.80*(par('usr')[4]-par('usr')[3]),
                      rect.col = cols,gradient="y",
                      legend = lc$Labels[seq(1,length(lc$Labels),3)])
```

[image]